# modify dc-count widget dimension/group in dc.js

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to add a dc-count-widget but I need to get around the default dimension/ group being all data/groupAll. My data looks like this:

```
`[{"subjId":"subj1", "temp":"37"},
  {"subjId":"subj1", "temp":"38"},
  {"subjId":"subj2", "temp":"36.5"},
  {"subjId":"subj2", "temp":"37.3"},
  {"subjId":"subj3", "temp":"39"}
]`
```

I want to add a dimension on temp "temperature" and a dc-count to reflect the count of unique subjects when I filter on ranges in temp.

EDIT
I tried:

```
subjectColumnName = 'subjId'
subjectDim = cfData.dimension(function(d) {return d[subjectColumnName]})
chart.dimension(subjectDim.group())
chart.group(subjectDim.groupAll())
```

but when filtering I get the duplicates count not unique counts of subjects.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [display the number of distinct items with data count widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27789872/display-the-number-of-distinct-items-with-data-count-widget)

Comment: Hi bernam, please check if this other question/answer suits your needs. If so, we should probably work on a feature to support this directly.

Comment: Or this one is more complete, but the app isn't letting me change my close vote: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099139/datacount-graph-filtered-by-a-dimension/30196842

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Gordon 
The solution in [dataCount graph filtered by a dimension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30099139/datacount-graph-filtered-by-a-dimension/30196842) would work, but the widget would not update if other charts are filtered so I had to create a custom group function to only count unique subjects.

I am not sure yet if the reduceRemoveSubj function is correct. And it looks like it's a very detoured solution!

Here it is:

```
function reduceAddSubj(p, v) {

            if( v[subjectColumnName] in p.subjects){
                p.subjects[v[subjectColumnName]]++
            }
            else {
                p.subjects[v[subjectColumnName]] = 1;
                ++p.count;
            }
            return p;
        }

function reduceRemoveSubj(p, v) {
            p.subjects[v[subjectColumnName]]--;
            if(p.subjects[v[subjectColumnName]] === 0){
                delete p.subjects[v[subjectColumnName]];
                --p.count;
            }
            return p;
        }

function initialSubj() {
            return {subjects: {},
                    count:0
            };
        }

subjectColumnName = 'subjId'
subjectDim = cfData.dimension(function(d) {return d[subjectColumnName]})
uniqueSubjGrp = subjectDim.groupAll().reduce(reduceAddSubj, reduceRemoveSubj, initialSubj)
uniqueSubjGrpM = {value: function() {
                return uniqueSubjGrp.value().count; 
            } };

chart.dimension(subjectDim.group())
chart.group(uniqueSubjGrpM)
```

Comment: That's odd, I wonder why the widget wouldn't update. It is tied to the chart group through the chart registry just like any other chart. This does seem like an awful lot of code for a simple feature, but I'm glad you got something working.